# Can I change the Dart/Flutter SDK versions on Dartpad.dev?

Tags: flutter, dart, dartpad

##### Context

I am currently working on a project that requires the use of [Dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/?id), and I'm looking to modify the Flutter/Dart SDK version for my specific needs.

In a typical environment, altering the SDK version can be achieved by updating the `pubspec.yaml` file like so:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"
```

However, I'm uncertain how this can be accomplished within Dartpad.dev, given its unique environment.

##### What I tried:

In an attempt to change the SDK version, I added the following line at the beginning of my dartpad file:

```
// @dart=2.9
```

Unfortunately, this resulted in an error message stating:

```
The language version must be >=2.12.0.
```

This leads me to wonder if it's even possible to downgrade the SDK version in this environment.

##### The question

- Is there a way to change the Flutter/Dart SDK version on Dartpad.dev? If so, what is the process?

---

###### Side note

I recall that in the pre-null-safety era, when the feature was still experimental, it was possible to alter a query parameter in the Dartpad link to allow for null safety.

However, my requirement goes beyond this, I am interested in changing the actual Dart SDK version, not just enabling or disabling null safety. Is this level of customization possible on Dartpad.dev?

###### Related

- [Turn off Null Safety for previous Flutter Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65302065/turn-off-null-safety-for-previous-flutter-project)

Comment: You can downgrade the language using the comments, just not lower than `2.12.0`. The dartpad website no longer supports those versions of dart. See https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/2115

Comment: Does your project require using the public, official version of Dartpad?  If not, then you probably could just host your own, older version: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad

Answer (score -1):

This might work, you can change the channel and run your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).